# How to modify restful_authentication plugin setup in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I installed restful_authentication a while ago in my project, everything works fine, except that now we requiere the users to activate their accounts via email.

I forgot to include the option "--include-activation" when I ran the generate script, is there a clean way to add it now? Or should I re-install the plugin? If so, how can it be done the safest and cleanest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go to the [generator source](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/blob/master/generators/authenticated/authenticated_generator.rb) and see what the `--include-activation` option does and replicate it manually. Very tedious, but I don't see another way.

Answer (score 0):

If your under source control you could branch your codebase and rerun the install with the flag '--include-activation' and see if it breaks your app or not.